# Read and write on JSON file with Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I have to load files from server and save to JSON file on Ionic project. I can load the file and the format is correct, see the picture below, but the next step I could not do, for lack of experience.

[image]

The problem is, I have to read the file ./assets/json/markings.json locally, remove the content and write the new content received from server.

My code where I am getting the JSON from server. Instead of console.log I have to save to markings.json

```
this._HttpService.get(`${ServerUrl.ApiUrl}marking`).then(data => {
  this.result = data;
  if (this.result.qtt > 0)
    console.log(JSON.stringify(this.result.response));

  else
    return;
})
```

The console.log

```
[
  {
    "_id": "60dd41ed35610e15649be7c9",
    "marking": "Aguardando fornecedor"
  },
  {
    "_id": "60dd41e635610e15649be7c7",
    "marking": "Em análise"
  }
]
```

Comment: you would POST the data back to the server and the server would write the file

Comment: Hello Roberto and welcome to Stack Overflow! you need to google for tutorials (and there are thousands) and try writing code first. This can help you get started: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hi @Felix .. thanks for this link, certainly many times I have doubt and the question is not well done..

Comment: @Bravo this case is not to save again on the server side, but save on the client side. The file markings.json exist and I want to remove the content and update with the data received from the server.

Comment: @RobertoVieira Try to think what do you need to achieve first of all and then you can achieve with the approach you described. Hint: the json you are getting comes from the server, it means it is stored there: why do you need to store it in the frontend?

Comment: @RobertoVieira - in that case you'll need to offer the file as a download - no, you can't tell the client where to save it

Answer (score 0):

I want to save these information on client side to avoid too many HTTP requests, these information is used all te time. So for test I will use localStorage and keep looking if is better or not using JSON on client side.

Created a service to handle the JSON.

```
import { Injectable, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class MarkingsService implements OnInit {

  constructor(
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() { }

  async removeMarkings() {
    localStorage.removeItem('markings');
    return;
  }

  async setMarkings(jsonOBJ) {
    localStorage.setItem('markings', JSON.stringify(jsonOBJ));
    return;
  }

  async getMarkings() {
    return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('markings'));
  }

}
```

And I have to make sure that always customer change any information, load the data again on localStorage.

On the pages, to get the markings.

```
  async getMarkings() {
    this._MarkingsService.getMarkings().then(data => {
      this.result = data;
      if (this.result.length > 0) {
        this.hasMarking = true;
        this.dataArray = this.result;
      }
      else {
        this.hasMarking = false;
        this.message = this._TranslocoService.translate('marking.noFound');
      }
    });
  }
```